# Getting database values grouped in an array

Tags: php, array, mysql, datetime

I have a database column with dates corresponding to sales orders. I get the count of orders in each month. Currently in my code, I use a `switch` statement. I know it is not a neat way of coding. So I need to know if there is any way I can do it more precisely. I need the output in such a way as below to form a chart in JavaScript.

```
$datayearly = array(
    'labels' => array('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'),
    'series' => array(array(
        'name' => 'series-1',
        'data' => array($jan, $feb, $mar, $apr, $may, $jun, $jul, $aug, $sep, $oct, $nov, $dec)
    ))
);
```

Php Code for fetching from database and screenshot of the database.
[image]

```
$thisyear =  date("Y");
$jan=$sep=$feb=$mar=$apr=$may=$jun=$jul=$aug=$sep=$oct=$nov=$dec=0;
$year[0] =0;
$stmt = $conn1->prepare("SELECT * FROM salessummary WHERE dateoforder LIKE :key");
$stmt->execute(array('key' => "%{$thisyear}%"));
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $month = date('m', strtotime($row['dateoforder']));
    switch ($month) {
        case "01":
        $jan++;
        case "02":
        $feb++;
        case "03":
        $mar++;
        case "04":
        $apr++;
        case "05":
        $may++;
        case "06":
        $jun++;
        case "07":
        $jul++;
        case "08":
        $aug++;
        case "09":
        $sep++;
        case "10":
        $oct++;
        case "11":
        $nov++;
        case "12":
        $dec++;
    }       
}
$high = max($jan, $feb, $mar, $apr, $may, $jun, $jul, $aug, $sep, $oct, $nov, $dec) + 10;
$datayearly = array(
    'labels' => array('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'),
    'series' => array(array(
        'name' => 'series-1',
        'data' => array($jan, $feb, $mar, $apr, $may, $jun, $jul, $aug, $sep, $oct, $nov, $dec)
    ))
);
$temp = json_encode($datayearly);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### SQL query

Of course, all the data calculations should be done on the database side. So the main improvement would be an SQL query like this

```
select upper(date_format(dateoforder, "%b")), count(1) 
from salessummary group by month(dateoforder);
```

#### PDO magic

Next, let's utilize the PDO's magic constant that can load your data into the neat associative array, [PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_KEY_PAIR), with month abbreviations as keys and order count for the given month as values

So our code would be

```
$thisyear =  date("Y");
$sql = "select upper(date_format(dateoforder, "%b")), count(1) 
        from salessummary group by month(dateoforder) WHERE dateoforder LIKE ?";
$stmt = $conn1->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array("$thisyear%"));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

#### Data gathering

It will give us the information for all the data that exists in the database, but with obvious gaps. To fill them, let's run a simple loop

```
$result = [];
foreach (range(1,12) as $num) {
    $mon = strtoupper(date("M", strtotime("$thisyear-$num-15")));
    $result[$mon] = $data[$mon] ?? 0;
}
```

and then assemble the final data structure

```
$datayearly = array(
    'labels' => array_keys($result),
    'series' => array(array(
        'name' => 'series-1',
        'data' => array_values($result)
    ))
);
```

Note that [the null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (i.e. `??`) exists in PHP7 only. If your PHP version is outdated, then you could use the old form,

```
     $result[$mon] = isset($data[$mon]) ? $data[$mon] : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Flaw with current code

The original output with the sample data appears to be:

```
{
    "labels":["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"],
    "series": [{            
        "name":"series-1",
        "data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,4,4]
    }]
}
```

Notice that the last 3 elements of the series data array are a `4`, when really the first of those should be a `3` and the other two should be a `0`, since there are only 4 records: 1 in September and three in October. This is because the `case`s of the `switch` statement do not contain `break`, and thus whenever a `CASE` line matches, every case after that is executed (and thus the associated counts for subsequent months get increased).

### Making the code work

The [answer by Your Common Sense](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179250/120114) is good, though there is still one thing that could be improved. Instead of using a `LIKE` operator and the string `[YEAR]%` for the on the dateoforder, use an [equals operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal) with [`YEAR(dateoforder)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year). Refer to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96249/104800) for a detailed explanation of why that should be used.

```
$sql = "select upper(date_format(dateoforder, '%b')), count(1) from salessummary WHERE year(dateoforder) = ? group by month(dateoforder) ";
```

And then the year parameter can be bound as an integer instead of a string:

```
$stmt->execute(array($thisyear));
```